# TYPO3: Site Configuration Data inside TSconfig Condition

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tsconfig

The divider content element is disabled for all pages via `TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems := addToList([…], div)` in PageTSconfig. This works just fine.

Now I want that the divider is only available for a certain subset of pages.
I defined the uppermost page in my site configuration which leads to the following Typoscript:

```
[site("configuration")["settings"]["pages"]["simpleLanguage"] and site("configuration")["settings"]["pages"]["simpleLanguage"] in tree.rootLineIds]
    TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems := removeFromList(div)
[END]
```

Now when I want to insert an divider on that given pages, I can choose it from the NewContentElement Wizard, but when the form of the content element gets rendered the divider is missing in the CType select.

[image: Divider is shown]

Divider is shown in NewContentElement Wizard

[image: Divider is missing here]

But not in the content element form.

I found out that when setting the pageuid directly, the condition is evaluated fine.
So my conclusion ist that I cannot get site information inside TSconfig.

**So how can I get the information from the site config inside TSconfig?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions in PageTS have been fixed for TYPO3 v10 with https://forge.typo3.org/issues/89718.

The patch has not been backported to v9 due to its complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The new content element wizard uses another configuration:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/Mod.html#newcontentelement-wizarditems

```
# PageTS
# CType "div" is in group "special"
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.special.show := removeFromList(div)
```

Comment: In the new content element wizard the divider is show und the tab "special". But when I click on it to add it to page, the form content element form which is shown, does not contain the divider in the CType select field. 

I will add an image to show where the divider is missing.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. You want to enable it for certain pages, not disable. Then you would use `addToList()`.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make my self clear either.

The divider is shown and hidden correctly, if I remove the condition around it. 

The condition itself seems to be problem. Why, you may ask? If I put the page uid directly into the condition instead of trying to read the uid (`site("configuration")["settings"]["pages"]["simpleLanguage"]`) from the site config it works fine.

I also use this condition in the frontend TypoScript where it also works without any problems.

So my guess is, that somehow I cannot read from the site config the same way in the backend as I do in the frontend.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem. For conditions I haven't asked which version you are using. For TYPO3 v10 https://forge.typo3.org/issues/89718 has fixed conditions. I am not aware of the state for TYPO3 v9

Comment: No hard feelings ;)
Seems to be the described bug. I tested my condition in v10 and it got evaluated correctly. If you could post you comment as answer, I will gladly accept it.